# split time interval in batch

Tags: bash

I have a python script that is used to gather data from a server. I can run it as :

```
./ApiStreamingClient.py -w flow-index -n admin -p admin localhost 1477389500000000000 1477389900000000000 | gzip - > out.gz
```

where `1477389500000000000` and `1477389900000000000` are time in nanoseconds defining an interval.

As the service is slow I need to write a bash script that run the same code in subintervals.

This is my current attempt but there are some errors while compiling:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_name=$1
data_type=$2
username=$3
password=$4
address=$5
start_time=$6
end_time=$7

set batch_size = 1000000000
set batch_start = start_time
set batch_end = current_time + batch_size

while (("$batch_end" < "$end_time"))

do

  echo "iteration $i batch_start=$batch_start batch_end=$batch_end"
  ./$file_name -w flow-index -n $username -p $password $address $batch_start $batch_end | gzip > "out
  set /a batch_start = batch_end + 1
  set /a batch_end = batch_start + batch_size
done
~
```

I think the error is in how the while loop is defined and in how I update the `batch_start` and `batch_end` variables.

Can you please explain me what's wrong with this code? My knowledge o bash is close to 0 and I would like to have the working version of the script and an explanation of the problems.

Thansk!

EDIT:
I still get errors:

```
#!/bin/bash

file_name=$1
data_type=$2
username=$3
password=$4
address=$5
start_time=$6
end_time=$7

batch_size = 1000000000
batch_start = $start_time
batch_end = $((current_time + batch_size))


while (("$batch_end" < "$end_time$))
do

  echo "iteration $i batch_start=$batch_start batch_end=$batch_end"
  ./$file_name -w flow-index -n $username -p $password $address $batch_start $batch_end | gzip > "out_$i.gz"
  batch_start =$((batch_end + 1))
  batch_end =$((batch_start + batch_size))
done
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
probe27:/data/misc # 
probe27:/data/misc # 
probe27:/data/misc # 
probe27:/data/misc # 
probe27:/data/misc # sh GetStreamingFlowData.sh ApiStreamingClient.py -w flow-index -n admin -p admin localhost 1477389500000000000 1477389900000000000
GetStreamingFlowData.sh: line 11: batch_size: command not found
GetStreamingFlowData.sh: line 12: batch_start: command not found
GetStreamingFlowData.sh: line 13: batch_end: command not found
GetStreamingFlowData.sh: line 20: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
GetStreamingFlowData.sh: line 24: syntax error: unexpected end of file
probe27:/data/misc #
```

Comment: Have you considered doing this in python? It would be more appropriate as python is more adapted to arithmetic and it would avoid adding another language to your process. I might be mistaken, but I'm pretty sure even if you haven't ever wrote a single line of python you could be able learn enough to do it in half a day

Comment: do you think it is too difficult in bash? I'm not sure I can use python

Comment: No, it's easy if you use the right tool, see my answer :) The problem is in the long-term : if something breaks in your solution, you may need both a ressource which knows python and a ressource that knows bash to debug it. Also bash is way less efficient than python, and spawning multiple python process instead of only one must also cost time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `seq` :

```
start=1477389500000000000
end=1477389900000000000
step=1000000000

for current_step in $(seq $start $step $end); do
    echo $current_step
done
```

Comment: Thanks do you mind to write also the python solution?

Comment: Well I'd like to but I'm currently busy, and not familiar with python that I could do it in a minute. I'll see if I can find enough time in the following hours, but you might as well open another question

Answer (score 0):

You have the syntax for assigning a value to a variable wrong. You are writing a *`bash`* script, not a DOS *`batch`* file.

```
#!/bin/bash

file_name=$1
data_type=$2
username=$3
password=$4
address=$5
start_time=$6
end_time=$7

batch_size=1000000000
batch_start=$start_time
batch_end=$((current_time + batch_size))

while (("$batch_end" < "$end_time"))

do

  echo "iteration $i batch_start=$batch_start batch_end=$batch_end"
  ./$file_name -w flow-index -n "$username" -p "$password" "$address" "$batch_start" "$batch_end" | gzip -c > out
  batch_start=$((batch_end + 1))
  batch_end=$((batch_start + batch_size))
done
```

Comment: @Donbeo you've got extra spaces : `variable = value` breaks, `variable=value` or `variable= value` work